# JavaScript AppendChild

Tags: javascript

Всем здрасти. )

есть некий JS Код:
scripts.js

```
mysite={
    addDiv: function()
    {
        var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
        var div=document.getElementById("myDiv");
        div.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

}
```

почему в таком случае ничего не работает:
somepage.html:

```
....
<script>
mysite.addDiv();
</script>
<body>
...
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

А в таком, всё работает:
    ....

```
<body onload="mysite.addDiv()">
...
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае скрипт работает до появления на странице div'а, поэтому и обламывается на попытке достучаться до него. Переместите script после div#myDiv - все заработает.

Comment: вот блин, точно. спасибо. )

Answer (score 1):

Правилом хорошего тона считается размещать скрипты в конце страницы (если они, конечно, не необходимы в процессе загрузки страницы), что бы избежать подобных ситуаций.

И хорошо бы подстраховаться чем-нибудь вроде этого:

`window.onload = function(){
    // код инициализации
}`